# 'View email as web page', how do I change language of this link to different in exacttarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to change language of 'view this email as a web page' from the email template in exacttarget. Is there any standard way to d it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'View this email as a webpage' is simply a `<a href>` html tag. You could simply create a copy of the template and edit the HTML

```
<a href="%%view_email_url%%" alias="VAWP">Your translated text goes here</a>
```

The copy of the email you see in the browser is a snapshot of the email that was sent.